# Interpretation of an elementary probability problem

Tags: probability

The following problem is from an introductory course of probability (MIT 6.041SC):

> Bob has a peculiar pair of four-sided dice. When he rolls the dice, the probability of any particular outcome is proportional to the sum of the results of each die. All outcomes that result in a particular sum are equally likely.

As a non-native English speaker, I found the last sentence hard to understand, if it is "well-said", then what exactly does it try to say?

(This is more like a question of the English language, than a question of math, since answering it requires some knowledge of math, I post the question here, not a language forum.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability to get $(1,4)$ is equal to the probability to the probability $(2,3)$, which is equal to the probability to get $(3,2)$, which is equal to the probability  to get $(4,1)$.

All of such outcomes sum to $5$.

Comment: So, the last sentence, "All outcomes ... equally likely", can be removed from the statement without losing any information? (since, from the second sentence, "When he ... each die", we already know that $P(\{(1, 4)\}) = P(\{(2, 3)\})$)

Comment: On a second thought, the last sentence is necessary: it adds a constraint such that $k_1 = k_2$, where $P(\{(1, 4)\}) = 5k_1$ and $P(\{(2, 3)\}) = 5k_2$.

Answer (score 0):

You may be correct about language as we seem to have interpreted the description differently

---

**An alternative approach based on your comment**

Presumably each die is numbered $1,2,3,4$

So the possible outcomes of the sum of two such dice are $2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ and these can occur in $1,2,3,4,3,2,1$ possible ways respectively (e.g. $6$ can be $2+4$ or $3+3$ or $4+2$, so three ways) and $1 \times 2 + 2 \times 3+ 3 \times 4+ 4 \times 5+ 3 \times 6+ 2 \times 7+ 1 \times 8 = 80$

Taking account of the number of of ways each outcome sum can occur gives the following probabilities for each pair

```
First die    Second die   Sum   Probability
   1             1         2     2/80 = 1/40 
   1             2         3     3/80  
   2             1         3     3/80  
   1             3         4     4/80 = 1/20 
   2             2         4     4/80 = 1/20 
   3             1         4     4/80 = 1/20
   1             4         5     5/80 = 1/16
   2             3         5     5/80 = 1/16 
   3             2         5     5/80 = 1/16 
   4             1         5     5/80 = 1/16 
   2             4         6     6/80 = 3/40 
   3             3         6     6/80 = 3/40 
   4             2         6     6/80 = 3/40
   3             4         7     7/80 
   4             3         7     7/80 
   4             4         8     8/80 = 1/10
```

so the probabilities of sums of $2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ are $\frac{1}{40}, \frac{3}{40}, \frac{3}{20}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{9}{40}, \frac{7}{40}, \frac{1}{10}$ respectively.  The probabilities a particular die shows $1,2,3,4$ are $\frac{7}{40}, \frac{9}{40}, \frac{11}{40}, \frac{13}{40}$ respectively and so the dice are not independent, making them particularly peculiar

---

**Original answer**

Presumably each die is numbered $1,2,3,4$

So the possible outcomes of the sum of two such dice are $2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ (which add up to $35$), and these can occur in $1,2,3,4,3,2,1$ possible ways respectively (e.g. $6$ can be $2+4$ or $3+3$ or $4+2$, so three ways)

Since the probability of each outcome sum are proportionate to the outcome sum, the probabilities of each outcome sum are $\frac{2}{35},\frac{3}{35},\frac{4}{35},\frac{5}{35},\frac{6}{35},\frac{7}{35},\frac{8}{35}$ respectively

Taking account of the number of of ways each outcome sum can occur gives the following probabilities for each pair

```
First die    Second die   Probability
   1             1            2/35 
   1             2            3/70 
   2             1            3/70 
   1             3            4/105 
   2             2            4/105 
   3             1            4/105 
   1             4            5/140 
   2             3            5/140 
   3             2            5/140 
   4             1            5/140 
   2             4            2/35 
   3             3            2/35 
   4             2            2/35 
   3             4            1/10 
   4             3            1/10 
   4             4            8/35
```

and as a check, those probabilities add up to $1$.  The dice are not independent, and that makes them particularly peculiar

Comment: This doesn't agree with the official solution, I believe that you misunderstood the second sentence, the probability of $(1, 1)$ is proportional to $2=1+1$, not to 35.

Comment: @Incömplete: The likelihood of a sum of $2$ is proportional to $2$, but probabilities add up to $1$ so the probability of a sum of $2$ is $\frac2{2+3+4+5+6+7+8}=\frac2{35}$.  The only way to get a sum of $2$ is $1+1$ so the probability of $(1,1)$ is $\frac{2}{35}$.  What is the book answer? Indeed, what is the book question?

Comment: $P(1,1) = 2 / 80$. It is not "The likelihood of a sum of 2 is proportional to 2", but "The likelihood of (1, 1) is proportional to 2". (In the case of sum 2, this is the same, since sum 2 only has one case, namely, (1, 1), but for other sums, this is different.)